# Reverse engineering a custom data file

Tags: reverse-engineering

At my place of work we have a legacy document management system that for various reasons is now unsupported by the developers. I have been asked to look into extracting the documents contained in this system to eventually be imported into a new 3rd party system.

From tracing and process monitoring I have determined that the document images (mainly tiff files) are stored in a number of 1.5GB files. These files seem to be read from a specific offset and then written to a tmp file that is then served via a web app to the client, and then deleted.

I guess I am looking for suggestions as to how I can inspect these large files that contain the tiff images, and eventually extract and write them to individual files.

Comment: "unsupported by the developers" doesn't really say whether the source code is available. Is it? If so, then you should be able to hack it up to be able to read these files, and that'll be the basis for your new converter.

Comment: The source code sadly is not available, there are various unmanaged dlls which the application calls to access the data contained in these files. From what information i have gathered so far I have determined that a database query is executed (sp_getDoc <docid>) that the application must use some of the returned data to calculate which bytes of the large file contain the actual tiff file that is being requested. There are two numeric fields returned that look like they could relate to a start and end position of a file.

Comment: Why can't you just grab the files by automatically requesting them all from the web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the TIFFs compressed in some way?  If not, then your job may be pretty easy:  stitch the TIFFs together from the 1.5G files.

Can you see the output of a particular 1.5G file (or series of them)?  If so, then you should be able to piece together what the bytes should look like for that TIFF if it were uncompressed.

If the bytes don't appear to be there, then try some standard compressions (zip, tar, etc.) to see if you get a match.

Answer (score 0):

I'd open a file, seek to the required offset, and then stream into a tiff object (ideally one that supports streaming from memory or file). Then you've got it.  Poke around at some of the other bits, as there's likely metadata about the document that may be useful to the next system.